# Using unique_ptr / shared_ptr with API functions returning resources as out parameters via pointer

Tags: pointers, winapi, c++11, smart-pointers, c++14

I’m catching up now with C++ 11/14 stuff in my current project. I have trouble using `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` with API functions returning resources as out parameters via pointer.

Let’s consider `DsGetDcName(..., __out PDOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO* ppDCI)` as an example.

Before c++11 there was a widespread pattern to work with Windows APIs. I would have a RIIA class that holds `PDOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO`, calls `NetApiBufferFree` in destructor, and has `PDOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO* operator&()` so that I can write:

```
info_ptr spInfo;
DsGetDcName(..., &spInfo);
```

Now with C++ 11/14 I see a lot of articles advocating for `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` with a custom deleter to release a resource in a proper way. And it really works well when a resource is returned as an r-value from a function (`LoadLibrary` is a good example of this).

One solution I found is to attach a raw-pointer to a smart pointer after the API call:

```
PDOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO pDCI = nullptr;
DsGetDcName(..., &pDCI);
std::unique_ptr<DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO, decltype(&NetApiBufferFree)> spInfo(pDCI, &NetApiBufferFree);
```

However, this is not the way I like. As far as I understand, new smart pointers were not designed to work for out parameters probably because of the ‘safty first’ approach.

Can something be really done here? Perhaps some kind of functor class serving as out parameter proxy so I can write `DsGetDcName(..., &out_param(spInfo))` ?

Comment: The whole purpose of `std::unique_ptr` is to apply [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for pointers. If you have a setup already doing so, I don't think you should change.

Comment: The problem is that `std::unique_ptr` does not provide an overridden `operator&` to access the address of the internal pointer so it can be passed to the API.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can make a temporary wrapper that will initialize your `std::unique_ptr` upon destruction:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Dsgetdc.h>
#include <Lm.h>

#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename D>
struct OutParameterWrapper
{
    OutParameterWrapper(std::unique_ptr<T, D>& Target) : m_Target(Target), m_pSource(nullptr)
    {
    }
    ~OutParameterWrapper()
    {
        m_Target.reset(m_pSource);
    }
    operator T**()
    {
        return &m_pSource;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<T, D>& m_Target;
    T* m_pSource;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO, decltype(&NetApiBufferFree)> spInfo(nullptr, NetApiBufferFree);
    DsGetDcName(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, OutParameterWrapper<DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO, decltype(&NetApiBufferFree)>(spInfo));
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

To have automatic deduction and have it work for both `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` you can do something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Dsgetdc.h>
#include <Lm.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Netapi32.lib")

#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename P>
struct OutParameterWrapper
{
    OutParameterWrapper(P& Target) : m_Target(Target), m_pSource(nullptr)
    {
    }
    ~OutParameterWrapper()
    {
        m_Target.reset(m_pSource);
    }
    operator T**()
    {
        return &m_pSource;
    }

    P& m_Target;
    T* m_pSource;
};

template<typename P>
OutParameterWrapper<typename P::element_type, P> MakeOutParameterWrapper(P& Target)
{
    return OutParameterWrapper<typename P::element_type,P>(Target);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO, decltype(&NetApiBufferFree)> spInfo(nullptr, NetApiBufferFree);
    std::shared_ptr<DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO> spInfo2(nullptr, NetApiBufferFree);
    auto nResult = DsGetDcName(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, MakeOutParameterWrapper(spInfo));
    DsGetDcName(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, MakeOutParameterWrapper(spInfo2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I also came up with a similar solution today and it works. Although I used a shorter form (class out) it still looks too massive and what is more important it does not work for both - unique_ptr and shared_ptr. I guess more template magic is needed.

Comment: @KirillKovalenko - after you gave more detailed constraints I updated the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

So far I came up with this code:

```
template<typename T>
class out
{
    T* _p;
    std::shared_ptr<T>& _sp;
public:
    out(std::shared_ptr<T>& sp) : _p(nullptr) , _sp(sp) {}
    ~out() { _sp.reset(_p); }
    T** operator&() { _ASSERT(nullptr == _p); return &_p; }
};
```

But it has 2 disadvantages

1. When used it looks heavy because class template type is not deduced from the constructor, e.g. I have to write `GetMeow(&out<Meow>(sp))` instead of `GetMeow(&out(sp))`
2. The same name does not work for simultaneously for `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`.

Are there any template ninjas?

EDIT:

Ok, I've combined Rudolfs' work with some of my tweaks and the final result is here: https://gist.github.com/kirillkovalenko/8219e7c1afea9b5da5da

Comment: When you want a template deduction on a class, use an external function. Look at `std::make_shared` of `std::make_pair`, that's their purpose.

Comment: In your case i'd use something like `template <class T> out<T> make_out(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr) {return (out<T>(ptr));}` [Just for formatting](http://ideone.com/G8ZUam)